# RewriteCond and rules except some page

Tags: apache

Hello I want use redirect module on apache2

if request "test.net/xxx" then redirect to "test.test..net/xxx"

but except index.html page

for example if request "test.net/index.html" then no redirect

i wrote the apache2 conf file as below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^http://test\.net/([^index\.html]) http://test.test.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but doesn't work

how to edit above sentences? please tell me

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add a condition to take care that the rule is only applied if the exception is *not* met and fix the actual rewriting rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.html$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://test.test.net/$1 [R=301]
```

That rule will work in the http servers host configuration but also in dynamic configuration files (".htaccess").

If you receive an http status 500 ("internal server error") with above rule then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apachE http server. The error log files will then point out an unknown flag `[END]`. Replace it with the old `[L]` flag in that case.

Comment: Thank for your answer 
i apply your advise then "test.net/xxx" to "test.test..net/xxx" is worked
but "test.net/index.html" is redirect to "test.test.net/index.html" also
I need more help, thanks

Comment: I do apologize, I made a small modification in the second condition, hopefully things work as expected now. The `%{REQUEST_URI}` contains an absolute path obviously, so a string with a leading slash...